# Outer loop not working with inner loop in Multi Statement Table Valued function in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I have a column name **col1** with values like -

```
abc,d,efg,value1| q,s,r,value2| z,x,v,value3| o,o,p,value4| i,ii,uu,value5|
```

I have created a function to split these values into columns. So that I get output like

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
---------------------
abc d efg value1
q s r value2
z x v value3
o o p value4
i ii uu value5
```

But the function that I have created is giving output as :

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
--------------------
abc d efg value1
abc d efg value1
abc d efg value1
abc d efg value1
abc d efgvalue1
```

Only the first row is correct.

My function is :

```
create function [dbo].[samarprocedure](@delm1 varchar(1),@delm2 varchar(1),@col1 varchar(100))
returns @tab table(str1 varchar(100),str2 varchar(100),str3 varchar(100), str4 varchar(100))
as
begin
declare @i int = 1
declare @j int = 1
declare @loc1 int = 1
declare @loc2 int = 1
declare @str varchar(100)
declare @str1 varchar(100)
declare @str2 varchar(100)
declare @str3 varchar(100)
declare @str4 varchar(100)
declare @loop1 int = len(@col1) - len(replace(@col1,@delm2,''))+1

set @col1 = ',' + REPLACE(@col1,@delm2,@delm1)
declare @loop int = len(@col1) - len(replace(@col1,@delm1,''))

while (@j<=@loop1)
begin

while (@i<=@loop)
    begin
                set @loc1 = charindex(@delm1,@col1,@loc2)
                set @loc2 = charindex(@delm1,@col1,@loc1+1)


                if @i = 1  
                set @str1 = SUBSTRING(@col1,@loc1+1,@loc2-1-@loc1)
                else
                if @i = 2 
                set @str2 = SUBSTRING(@col1,@loc1+1,@loc2-1-@loc1)
                if @i = 3
                set @str3 = SUBSTRING(@col1,@loc1+1,@loc2-1-@loc1)
                if @i = 4  
                set @str4 = SUBSTRING(@col1,@loc1+1,@loc2-1-@loc1)
                set @i = @i + 1



    end
insert into @tab
values(@str1, @str2,@str3,@str4)
set @j = @j + 1

end
return
end
```

Now I am calling the above function from the below code :

```
declare @arg varchar(100) = 'abc,d,efg,value1| q,s,r,value2| z,x,v,value3| o,o,p,value4| i,ii,uu,value5|'
select * from dbo.samarprocedure(',','| ',@arg)
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: The performance of this is going to be horrible. Multi statement table valued functions are often slower than their scalar function counterparts. Scalar functions are notoriously awful at performance. Then in your implementation you have nested loops. You need to look at this article first. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings Find any of the string split functions from there. Then you can use it twice to parse this denormalized string into the usable data you are trying to do.

Comment: @sean-  Just for understanding purpose can you let me know what is wrong in the above code why outer loop is repeating the same values. It seems like loc1 and loc2 are loosing there values every time inner loop finishes

Comment: No offense but I have no interest in debugging this. It should be replaced with much simpler code that will also outperform this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally like the splitter referenced as the "Moden" version. You can find it [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/). It has some limitations and some people disagree with it but regardless of the splitter you pick your code would end up being something like this.

```
declare @arg varchar(100) = 'abc,d,efg,value1| q,s,r,value2| z,x,v,value3| o,o,p,value4| i,ii,uu,value5|'

;
with FirstSplit as
(
    select * 
    from dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@arg, '|')
)

select fs.ItemNumber
    , x.Item
from FirstSplit fs
cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(item, ',') x
where fs.Item > ''
```